# Problem with running a script as a startup program

Tags: scripting, startup, mx-linux

I wrote a script and added it to `/usr/bin/` with the permission for execution. It works exactly as expected when I run it on terminal. The script is written for updating the TeX-system regularly, add a time-stamp to this process and display the output with a text-editor. In the following code, `tlmgr` is the program for managing/updating/installing TeX-related packages and programs; `tlmgr-update` is the name of the output file and `gedit` is a text editor.

```
#!/bin/sh
tlmgr update --all > tlmgr-update
date >> tlmgr-update
gedit tlmgr-update
```

Now this script works absolutely fine when called by its name on the terminal. A sample output would be something like this when called from the terminal.

```
tlmgr: package repository https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2021/tlpkg/backups
[1/8, ??:??/??:??] update: beebe [863k] (59956 -> 60238) ... done
[2/8, 00:11/02:36] update: easybook [624k] (60221 -> 60243) ... done
[3/8, 00:19/02:36] update: hvlogos [77k] (60126 -> 60236) ... done
[4/8, 00:24/03:08] update: media9 [7224k] (60110 -> 60244) ... done
[5/8, 01:16/01:45] update: tex4ht [2202k] (60231 -> 60245) ... done
[6/8, 01:32/01:42] update: texlive-scripts [496k] (60219 -> 60238) ... done
[7/8, 01:37/01:43] update: tikzbricks [253k] (60211 -> 60234) ... done
[8/8, 01:43/01:47] update: xindex [502k] (59875 -> 60242) ... done
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: command log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
Sun 15 Aug 2021 08:24:37 PM IST
```

but when I add it as a startup command on my MX Linux computer, it just adds the timestamp to a file named tlmgr-update and opens it. `tlmgr` is not run. Is this a bug for tlmgr, or my distro? My system specifications are as follows.

```
cat /etc/*-release
NAME="MX"
VERSION="19 (patito feo)"
ID="mx"
VERSION_ID="19"
PRETTY_NAME="MX 19 (patito feo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;34"
HOME_URL="https://mxlinux.org"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://mxlinux.org"
PRETTY_NAME="MX 19.4 patito feo"
DISTRIB_ID=MX
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.4 
DISTRIB_CODENAME="patito feo"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="MX 19.4 patito feo"
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Where is `tlmgr` located? Perhaps it is on the PATH of your interactive shell, but not on the `PATH` when run from your session's startup applications. Adding `2>&1` after `> tlmgr-update` to capture errors into the same file might be helpful.

Comment: What does "add it as a startup command" mean exactly? `gedit` is usually a graphical editor, so will need a logged in user and a `DISPLAY` variable set. Does your script produce the correct output if you invoke it as `env - PATH=/bin:/usr/bin scriptname`? If not there may be some other environment variables that are required.

Comment: @steeldriver `tlmgr` is located in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux`. I have set the path in `.bashrc` _as well as_ `.profile`. This shall suffice right? Does your last suggestion mean this on line 2 of my script? `tlmgr update -a > tlmgr-update 2>&21` shall it be without space or with space?

Comment: @icarus MX linux has a menu named `Session and startup`. You can add any script or commands in it and it will be run when you log in to the device. I think the problem is not with `gedit` as it gets opened correctly. The only problem is the first command (line 2) is not working. '`tlmgr update -a`'s output is not written on the file `tlmgr-update`. Timestamp is correctly added to the file which is coded by `date >> tlmgr-update` and the file is also correctly opened which is coded by `gedit tlmgr-update`. `tlmgr-update` file after the startup process looks like `Mon Aug 16 10:07:36 IST 2021`

Comment: @steeldriver when I added `2>&1` to the file, the `gedit tlmgr-update` didn't work, but first line of output says `/bin/tex-update-daily: 2: /bin/tex-update-daily: tlmgr: not found`. Note that timestamp is still getting appended.

Comment: @steeldriver You were right. Adding `2>&1` was helpful; it was a path problem. After reading this error I understood the problem. I added the full path to the command and then it worked! Thanks a lot! You may add some explanation as an answer so that it can be useful for others too and I can accept it.